# Rolling mean partinioned by different columns in R

Tags: r

I'm working in R and I need to do a rolling mean of the last 3 values of a data set, partitioned by 3 different columns. Each time one of the values of the column changes, the rolling mean should restart the rolling.

The following example portrays my objective:

```
Material   Channel   client   value   mean   
---------------------------------------------
    1         2        2        5      NA
    1         2        2        10     NA
    1         2        2        7      7,3
    1         2        2        10     9
    1         2        5        5      NA
    1         2        5        3      NA
    1         2        5        5      13
```

I've tried to use the rollmean function, but it doesn't partition the dataset by columns.

```
input_mes_cluster[, peso_medio:=rollmean(peso, k = 12) , by= c("cluster","material","canal", "cliente", "regiao")]
```

How can I get the expected result?

Thanks!

Comment: Unless "partinion" is some term I don't know, I think you mean "partition"?

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(roll)

data.frame(Material = rep(1,7), 
           Channel = rep(2,7), 
           client = c(2,2,2,2,5,5,5), 
           value = c(5,10,7,10,5,3,5)) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  group_by(Material, Channel, client) %>% 
  mutate(mean = roll::roll_mean(as.matrix(value), width = 3))
```

Comment: Can you explain what this code does and why it works?

Comment: Tried this one out and it doesn't change anything in the data frame

Comment: @DiogoSá What do you mean: "it doesn't change anything in the data frame"?